# Ubuntu: valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'amd64-linux': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind

I have installed valgrind with no problems but when running it I keep getting the following error:

```
valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'amd64-linux': No such file or directory
```

I have adjusted my bash file accordingly. I added the following path: `/usr/bin/valgrind` from using: `which valgrind` command and it's still not working. Then I added the path:`/usr/lib/valgrind` and it is still not working. I think I am confused about the correct local directory for using Ubuntu.

I am using:

```
export VALGRIND_LIB="/usr/lib/valgrind"
```

Do I have to add my local directory first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add "export VALGRIND_LIB=/usr/lib/valgrind/"(or /usr/local/lib/valgrind/ or other place where you install your valgrind lib) into ~/.bashrc

Comment: This does not work with 3.17.0. See @paul Floyd answer.

Answer (score 14):

I built valgrind from source and the posted answer did not work for me but this did:

e.g. how i configured:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/valgrind
```

What I added to my `~/.bashrc`

```
export VALGRIND_LIB=$HOME/local/valgrind/libexec/valgrind
```

Seems like it needed `libexec`, not `lib`

Comment: This is what worked for me.

Comment: For some reason, when I got 3.16.1 going in my arm/linux environment, /opt/lib/valgrind/  did the trick. Upgrading to 3.20.0, for some reason this error popped up and I had to edit my export to /opt/libexec/valgrind/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set any environment variables, unless you are working on the code of Valgrind itself.

Just run /usr/bin/valgrind. This will then run /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux and preload some .so files in the same directory.

I don't have much experience with Debian/Ubuntu, but if you installed it with snap then afaict you should use the --classic option.

Comment: I have confirmed that this fixes running with `valgrind/3.17.0`. All that it is needed is the $PATH set, not `VALGRIND_LIB`. Setting `VALGRIND_LIB` breaks it.  With `valgrind/3.15.0`, the VALGRIND_LIB might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
export VALGRIND_LIB=<where libexec/valgrind is|where massif-arm64-linux is>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are using a 64bit valgrind for 64 bit executable, using a 32 bit valgrind on a 64 bit exe resuts in this error

> /tmp>file /usr/bin/valgrind /usr/bin/valgrind: ELF 32-bit LSB
> executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses
> shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
>
> /tmp>file a.out a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1
> (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18,
> not stripped
>
> /tmp>valgrind a.out valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for
> platform 'amd64-linux': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

As the others indicated above, you need export VALGRIND_LIB="path-to-valgrind-lib". If "/usr/lib/valgrind" or "/usr/local/lib/valgrind" does not work, check "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind" too if you are on linux.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions proposed worked for me, so I enabled all optional modules:

`./configure --enable-only64bit --enable-inner  --enable-lto --enable-tls`

et voila, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error is seen when 32 bit valgrind is used for 64 bit executable. Install 64 bit version of valgrind to resolve the issue.

```
yum install valgrind.x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run using "sudo", in my case it helped.